# Qt application depends on dll's (which it doesn't need?)

Tags: c++, qt, dll

I am compiling a Qt Webkit application and I understand webkitwidgets depends on a fair few dll's, however does every Webkit application required all these 20+ dll's to be shipped? Or am I doing something wrong here. This is every DLL needed to run my program.

[image: Too many dll's!]

CFF Explorer only shows these 10 DLLs:

[image]

The app comes to a hefty ~150mb so any way to reduce this? I wanted to compile statically however you cannot use webkit that way.

Comment: Don't want bloat? Don't pick Qt.

Comment: Indeed but since I picked Qt to develop this with I'm not changing now, I guess I could find a way of not using WebKit in my app but I need js :/

Comment: @GregHewgill I needed the js to interact with a web page, I'm display a google map

Comment: 150mb is not an unreasonable size for an application with its own embedded web browser. On Windows you do have the option of using the operating system's native Internet Explorer engine (via the IWebBrowser2 COM interface) but that's probably not worth the headache.

Comment: I guess it isn't too bad, I hate having to ship lots of DLL's but if it means avoiding the Internet Explorer engine then I'm all for it

Answer (score 0):

Open your Qt command promp.

```
mkdir installer
cd installer
```

Copy your generated exe file to this folder. And run:

```
windeployqt .
```

This command will copy all files you need. Use DependencyWalker for more info. 
WARNING: some dlls are copied to be used in other OS version, so dont remove it, specially if you want that your app be compatible from Windows XP to Windows 10.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/57c1e4e342f506cad9c6e9adf09809de.png I tried this earlier and still the same deps

Comment: I recommend to attach all files with your installer. From official doc: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html  "he Windows deployment tool is designed to automate the process of creating a deployable folder containing the dependencies (libraries, QML imports, plugins, and translations) that are required to run the application from that folder. It creates a sandbox for Windows Runtime or an installation tree for Windows desktop applications, which can be easily bundled into an installation package. The tool can be found in QTDIR/bin/windeployqt."

Comment: Still there are a lot of unnecessary files included. For example. If you are using SQLite, windeployqt will copy all sql drivers. Keep only the SQLite driver and delete the rest.

Comment: Use ProcessExplorer from Microsoft to get the list of the used DLL files during the running process. http://filehippo.com/es/download_process_explorer/